Martial arts master fights different European experts?
I am trying to identify a movie. I could've sworn it was a movie about IP Man, but I have tried watching all the ones I could get my hands on and couldn't find it.
All I remember about the movie started with a martial arts expert facing off against different Europeans and beating them. He fought against a very Spanish-looking man in a sword fight and defeated him, he fought against a Dutch-looking man in a pike/halberd/spear looking weapon and defeated him, and I think he might've also fought against a British-looking boxer and one or two other people. 

IP Man 2 definitely features a English Boxer but it doesn't have the Spanish or Dutch man.

It is Fearless but these things happened at the end.
Edit:
You can check this video. Jet Li is the actor. His father was a Master. He wanted to beat all masters, that was the only aim for him. Then he loses his family because of his ambition. He leaves the town and loses himself. But His mental health is cured in a small village. Then he returns back to his town, but learns that China is occupied. He meets his best friend. In the meeting he decides to join a tournament to defend China's honour against Trading Community. At last he learns forgiveness. He has understood his father's aim. Forgiveness is more important than beating all masters.
Things you told happened at this tournament.

Accepted since you were first

It's the Jet Li movie Fearless
In the movie the villains (the Japanese if I remember correctly), wanting to crush the spirit of the Chinese people bring in champions from other countries to defeat the local champion of China (played by Jet Li).  These include the mentioned swordsman, spearman and wrestler (not boxer), as well as a Japanese martial artist with a katana. 

Sorry your answer is correct and and has details (+1) but i had to accept the answer that identified the movie first
